# How do I customize the URL that Ember RESTAdapter calls?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In our Ember application, I have 3 different models:

- organizations
- users
- issues

Issues are created by users who belong to an organization. Both `organizations` and `users` have an `issues` array with a bunch of issue IDs that belong in the `issues` model. For example, this is what the `users` model looks like:

```
// app/models/users.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    belongsTo: DS.belongsTo('organizations'),
    issues: DS.hasMany('issues')
});
```

We have two APIs to view a list of all issues:

- `GET /users/:userId/issues` - This API gets all the issues created by the user
- `GET /organizations/:organizationId/issues` - This API gets all the issues created by users that belong to this organization

The issue is, when I call `this.store.findAll('issues');`, the Ember RESTAdapter calls `GET /issues` by default. I can't figure out a way to get the RESTAdapter to call any of the URLs above. I can't use `this.store.findRecord('issues', 1);` because that calls a specific issue by ID like `GET /issues/:issueId`. How can I get the RESTAdapter to call the above URLs without having to manually make an AJAX request and push the API response to Ember Data?

Comment: @kristjanreinhold No, it just fires `GET /issues/:id` where `:id` is the first ID in the `issues` array in the `users` model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize your adapter (you can have an adapter per-model if you want, as far as I know).

In your specific example I think you want to customize the [`urlForFindAll`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#method_urlForFindAll) method.

```
// maybe in app/organization/adapter.js (if using pods for a model specific  adapter)
urlForFindAll(modelName) {
    return 'urlYouWantToUseWithOrganizations';
}
```

A good article on this situation is on [Ember Igniter](https://emberigniter.com/fit-any-backend-into-ember-custom-adapters-serializers/)